# Overwrite Spreadsheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to open a new Spreadsheet every time a script(GAS) executes. Unfortunately, the SpreadsheetApp.create() keeps creating 'multiple' copies of the same file, with the same name. How do I overwrite the contents of file that already exists on the drive?

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear to me: do you want to open a **new** or an **existing** spreadsheet? `.create(name)` names the file as you request - if you want different names, you shold specify different names on each call. If you want to overwite am existing file you should avoid `.create()` and use `.openById()` instead.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written. Code speaks louder than words

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SpreadsheetApp.create()` to make a new spreadsheet file with a given name, but there is no equivalent `SpreadsheetApp.open()` function that accepts a file name. As you've found, `.create()` will **always** create a new file - it doesn't care if a file with that name already exists.

If you want to open a file name to open a spreadsheet, you need to find that file first, and then pass the [File Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file.html) to `SpreadsheetApp.open()`.

This utility function will either open an existing spreadsheet, or create one if no such file exists.

```
/**
 * Returns the Spreadsheet with the given file name. If no such spreadsheet
 * exists, it will be created.
 */
function openSheetByName(filename) {
  if (arguments.length == 0 || filename =="") throw new Error( "Missing filename." );

  var files = DocsList.getFilesByType('spreadsheet');
  var sheet;
  var i = 0;
  // Loop over all spreadsheet files. Loop ends when we reach the end,
  // or if we find a matching filename.
  while ( i < files.length && (files[i].getName() !== filename) )
    i++;

  if (i == files.length) {
    // We didn't find the file, so create it.
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
  }
  else {
    // We found it, use it.
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files[i]);
  }
  return sheet;
}
```

Here's a modified version of the `readRows()` example that uses the utility function.

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = openSheetByName("Favourite");

  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of Google Apps Services the script given by @Mogsdad to open an existing sheet can be modified as such to open the existing sheet or create a new one if its doesn't exist

```
/**
* Returns the Spreadsheet with the given file name. If no such spreadsheet
* exists, it will be created.
*/
function openSheetByName(filename) 
{
    if (arguments.length == 0 || filename =="") throw new Error( "Missing filename." );

        var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
        var sheet;
        // Check we found a sheet with the name
        while ( files.hasNext())
        {
            sheet = files.next();
            if(sheet.getName() == filename)
            {
                Logger.log("Opened Sheet: " + filename);
                return SpreadsheetApp.open(sheet);
            }
       }

      // We didn't find the file, so create it.
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
      Logger.log("Created new Sheet for: " + filename);
      return sheet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Sheet.clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear%28%29).

There are few options for deleting contents and formatting [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).